# Unable to reference instance of PersonsRepository interface

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am working from the Spring data tutorial here: http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/data/3/

I am trying to get my Spring 4 + Hibernate app up and running. I have created the following unit test according to the guide:

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.corrisoft.air.db.integration;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionConfiguration;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.corrisoft.air.db.JPAConfiguration;
import com.corrisoft.air.db.repository.PersonsRepository;
import com.corrisoft.air.model.Person;

    /**
     * @author Corrisoft Android Development
     *
     */
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = {JPAConfiguration.class})
    @Transactional
    @TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
    public class PersonsRepositoryIntegerationTests {

          @Autowired
          PersonsRepository personsRepository;

          @Test
          public void thatItemIsInsertedIntoRepoWorks() throws Exception {
            int id = 42;

            Person person = new Person();
            person.setId(id);

            person.setFirstName("Zaphod");
            person.setLastName("Beeblebrox");

            personsRepository.save(person);

            Person retrievedPerson = personsRepository.findById(id);

            assertNotNull(retrievedPerson);
            assertEquals(id, retrievedPerson.getId());
          }
    }

This tests the repository that I've created here:

    /**
     * 
     */
    package com.corrisoft.air.db.repository;

    import com.corrisoft.air.model.Person;
    import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

    /**
     * @author Corrisoft Android Development
     *
     */
    public interface PersonsRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Integer>{
        Person findById(long id);
    }
```

And I'm getting the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.corrisoft.air.db.repository.PersonsRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1100)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 28 more
```

The docs say that a proxy object will be created from the interface if I have the JPAConfuration class like this:

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.corrisoft.air.db;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.FilterType;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateExceptionTranslator;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import com.corrisoft.air.db.repository.PersonsRepository;

/**
 * @author Corrisoft Android Development
 * 
 */
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.corrisoft.db.repository",
                       includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(value = { PersonsRepository.class }, type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE))
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JPAConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        return builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() throws SQLException {

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan("com.corrisoft.air.model");
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();

        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManager entityManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws SQLException {
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
        return txManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateExceptionTranslator hibernateExceptionTranslator() {
        return new HibernateExceptionTranslator();
    }
}
```

I've already found several issues with the tutorial and am thinking this is another.

Comment: the tutorial mentions having a `OrdersRepository` interface that extends `CrudRepository`. Do you have this?

Comment: Never create a `@Bean` method that returns the EntityManager this breaks proper tx support. Spring will manage that for you.

Comment: @M.Deinum I am following the tutorial. What's a poor developer to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are scanning wrong package for repositories:

```
... basePackages = "com.corrisoft.db.repository" ...
```

whereas the correct one is

```
import com.corrisoft.air.db.repository.PersonsRepository;
```